# How can I open the terminal and run shell commands in custom eclipse plugin like cp or mv?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I am new to eclipse development. Trying to create a plugin which will copy files from one directory to another.
Introduced the menu as follows

[image: Sample Menu/Copy Files menu item]

Now on click of the Copy Files menu I want to copy file/s. For that I want to run the command

```
cp file1.txt ../dir/file1.txt
```

I have handler as follows which will be executed once I click on menu.

```
public class SampleHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        return null;
    }
}
```

How can I run the above command in my `handler.execute()` method to copy the files?

Comment: That doesn't sound very integrated, nor cross-platform. Have you considered reading and writing the files in your own code?

Comment: no. can you give any documentation or tutorial for the same?

Comment: https://help.eclipse.org/2019-06/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/ResourcesPlugin.html Is the class to get the workspace and find the IFiles of interest, assuming they're not somehow attached to the handler's event. Use a combination of `IFile#getContents()`, `IFile#create()`, and `IFile#setContents()` to handle the I/O.

Answer (score 1):

Consider reading and writing the files in your own code. Relying on external shell applications is not portable.

`PlatformUI` is the starting point to get the `IWorkspace` instance and get the source and target `IFiles` for your reading and writing. Use a combination of `IFile#getContents()`, `IFile#create()`, and `IFile#setContents()` to handle the actual I/O.